# Confused using indexOf(array type , String type)

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

```
private int findTaskById(String tID) {

  for(Task t: this.projectTasks) {
    if(t!=null && t.getTaskID().equals(tID) ) {
      return t.indexOf(tID); 
    }
}
```

I'm searching for the taskID in an array of projectTasks and I want to return its index, meaning the position it has in the array and I saw online I can use the object.indexOf(String type) method. It cannot recognise the indexOf(String type) in my program. Obviously, I'm doing something very wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no `indexOf()` method of class `Object`. Have you defined one in `Task`?

Comment: `t` is a `Task`, not a `List`, it doesn't seem to have a `indexOf` method. Either use a classic loop and return the index or implement the `equals` method for `Task` and use streams with `findFirst`

Comment: As per your, the return statement should be like this. ```return t.getTaskID().indexOf(tID); ```